# Can Necromancers repeatedly animate skeletons which have been defeated?

Tags: dnd-5e, necromancy

One of my players is saying they can use *animate dead* (3rd level, Necromancy) to repeatedly bring back their skeleton minions.

> This spell creates an Undead servant. Choose a pile of bones or a corpse of a Medium or Small Humanoid within range. Your spell imbues the target with a foul mimicry of life, raising it as an Undead creature. The target becomes a Skeleton if you chose bones or a Zombie if you chose a corpse (the DM has the creature's game statistics).

First time I've come across this, so I said hang on surely damage would break the bones? Shards of bone are not the same as a bone. "If you really wants to reanimate that particular skeleton, roll for it. For example Reanimation of a dead skeleton  DC= 5 + negative hp of skeleton + Int modifier. If the skeleton had 7 hp left and took 9 damage, your Int is +3. Then the DC= 5+2+3"

But this is perhaps overcomplicated.
I've settled on "One of the things that makes a necromancer cool is their undead horde. Why allow a player to take necromancy and then penalise their playstyle.
Caveat: I reserve the right to have certain traps/effects/events destroy them utterly. e.g. massive fire/acid damage."

Are there any clearer guidelines on this, please? How do you run this situation? **What might cause an undead to be irreparable?**

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Excellent post, thanks for the link, answered much of my query.I'm looking for the final bit in bold as well though. What might cause an undead (skeleton) to be irreparable? From the post you linked to, sounds like nothing, but that seems unreasonable.

Comment: @BrianWesterman Effects which cause the destruction of a creature's body are rare in dnd, because it would generally apply to players too. An example is the Disintegrate spell. There are to my knowledge no specific guidelines, beyond the aforementioned spells, for what would cause an pile of bones to become invalid for animation. If you are looking for sensible suggestions from people here you could make a new question which focuses on that specific question or rephrase this one and wait for it to be reopened.

Comment: **Historical note:** This is one of those things that has been ruled differently in different editions of the game. For example, 3.5rd edition D&D's version of the spell explicitly stated that "a destroyed skeleton or zombie can't be animated again." 2e AD&D had two different versions of the spell; the wizard version of the spell included a caveat that a skeleton or corpse had to be mostly intact for the spell to work, but the priest version did not.